How to model this mesh section of a hand watch
I'm attempting to model a hand watch. In the reference images, this section indicates its blended with the circle shape of the watch. I added 64 vertex circle to try match the blue print where the LUG of the watch is. But even 64 vertices dont match, so I can extrude and make the LUG.
If I grab the vertices to reposition them closer to where the LUG starts, I lose the circle shape which is 100%.
Here's a reference image which shows the LUG and the




Sliding the vertex closer, alters the shape of the circle.


Hello, if you meve the vertices a bit so that it matches the picture, it won't be noticeable, so I guess you can do it

One of the many ways how you can do this is using the Loop Cut and Slide tool to create extra cuts where you need them without changing the shape of the circle.
Press Ctrl+R to activate the tool, hover your mouse over the area where you need the extra cut until the yellow line indicates the correct cut, then click once to confirm you want to cut there, then you can slide the cut along the edges until it is in the correct position.

If you don't want to cut the circle completely towards the center and do not mind having n-gons afterwards, you could also in Edge Select mode just select the two edges where you need extra vertices, then right-click and choose Subdivide from the context menu. Then go to Vertex Select, select one of the new vertices and press G twice to activate Edge Slide, then slide the vertex to where you need it and repeat the same with the other.


Ok I got it, thanks for the GIF demo, helped me well with the 2 solutions. I thought this method would be incorrect if I slide the vertices because the circle shape would add more geometry, but my result is good for my first attempt. Cheers.
